# How to reverse array in bash onliner FOR loop?

Tags: bash

How can I reverse the order in which I perform a for loop for a defined array

To iterate through the array I am doing this:

```
$ export MYARRAY=("one" "two" "three" "four")
$ for i in ${MYARRAY[@]}; do echo $i;done
one
two
three
four
```

Is there a function where I can reverse the order of the array?

One thought I had is to generate a sequence of inverted indexes and call the elements by using this reversed index but maybe there is a quicker alternative, or at least easier to read.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the C-style for loop:

```
for (( idx=${#MYARRAY[@]}-1 ; idx>=0 ; idx-- )) ; do
    echo "${MYARRAY[idx]}"
done
```

For an array with "holes", the number of elements `${#arr[@]}` doesn't correspond to the index of the last element. You can create another array of indices and walk it backwards in the same way:

```
#! /bin/bash
arr[2]=a
arr[7]=b

echo ${#arr[@]}  # only 2!!

indices=( ${!arr[@]} )
for ((i=${#indices[@]} - 1; i >= 0; i--)) ; do
    echo "${arr[indices[i]]}"
done
```

Comment: The echo is not 100% foolproof but this is the best method to loop through an array in reverse order! `+1`

Comment: in `zsh`, at least, unless you change `idx=${#MYARRAY[@]}-1` to `idx=${#MYARRAY[@]}` the last element in the array will always be removed.

Comment: @AlexejMagura: The question is tagged `bash`. I tested the code in bash. Without `-1`, an empty line is printed at the beginning. `${#array[@]}` returns the number of elements, which is not the same as the index of the last element.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - I disagree. I think the one I demonstrate is foolproof.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It works for bash. And zsh. If the zsh_version environment variable is set it behaves as if its a zsh array, otherwise its a bash array. Also, there would be no problems with echo, and it should be much faster as it doesnt have to loop. Whats more, it actually sets a new current environment array in the process.

Comment: What if there are "holes" in the array?

Comment: @allyourcode: You can extract the indices to another array and walk that: `other=("${!withholes[@]}")`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: should that not be `... idx=${#MYARRAY[@]}  ; idx > 0 ; idx -- ...`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Weird. When I replace my code with yours, I don't get the `a` back.

Comment: @choroba: I am referring to the example without "holes" (that is the first piece of code you posted).

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: I'm not getting the first element, and the first returned value is empty.

Answer (score 29):

You can use [tac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tac_%28Unix%29), which is an opposite of `cat` in sense that it reverses the lines.

```bash
MYARRAY=("one" "two" "three" "four")
for item in "$MYARRAY"; do
   echo "$item"; 
done | tac

# four
# three
# two
# one
```

Comment: I don't advise this methods for several reasons: Useless use of a forking through `tac` and missing quotes!

Comment: Also note that `tac` is usually only available on Linux boxes.

Comment: @D.Shawley This is `bash`.

Comment: @jwg looks like a shell script snippet using a command that is usually only available on Linux boxes.  IOW, not just bash but bash in a GNU Linux environment.

Comment: I can confirm that `tac` is not available on OSX.

Comment: shouldn't that be `for item in "${MYARRAY[@]}"; do` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
_arr+=( '"${_arrev} is an actual "${array[@]}"' )  ⏎
_arr+=( '"${_arrev} is created as a result"' )
_arr+=( '"of reversing the key order in"' )
_arr+=( '"this "${_arr}. It handles zsh and"' )
_arr+=( '"bash arrays intelligently by tracking"' )
_arr+=( '"shell "$ENV." quotes=fine ( i hope ) "' )

. <<REVERSE /dev/stdin                    ⏎
    _arrev=( $(: $((l=${#_arr[@]}${ZSH_VERSION++1})) ; printf '"${_arr[$(('$l'-%d))]}" ' `seq 1 $l`) )
REVERSE

echo ; printf %s\\n ${_arrev}

"shell "$ENV." quotes=fine ( i hope ) "
"bash arrays intelligently by tracking"
"this "${_arr}. It handles zsh and"
"of reversing the key order in"
"${_arrev} is created as a result"
"${_arrev} is an actual "${array[@]}"
```

This should handle any possible array, I think.

If you're interested in what's going on up there, I suggest you have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120528/how-to-define-similar-bash-function-at-once/120531#120531) first. Then maybe [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120475/how-can-i-pass-argument-stored-on-a-variable-to-wget/120487#120487), definitely [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119845/52934), and, if you've got the time, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120863/52934) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120736/parsing-process-command-line-arguments-from-pargs-in-a-shell-script/120817#120817).

In all of those answers I discuss different 
aspects of the here-document *(and in many others)* which you can use to your advantage. For instance I discuss twice-evaluating variables, which is done above, and in one declare a function that globally declares another function named *`"_$1"`* in just 5 or 6 lines - most of which were *`_$1() { func body ; }`.* It's pretty handy if you use it correctly.

Regarding the auto-switch between *`bash/zsh,`*  well that's something else, but very simple as well. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008).

Comment: Interesting method. Please add some explanations. Also, the OP seemed to want to _print_ the content of the array (even though it's not clearly stated); please also adapt your answer for only printing the array in reverse order.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've linked to different answers in which I've already explained the fundamentals of what it's doing. Honestly, though, I don't even know how arrays work - I never use them. I know this works and can't fail thanks to *`printf`* and the *`shell`* doing the rest. Hope I helped.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf ***Only*** printing? Easily done, but i dont know where it is you came up with it as a requirement. If you desire *only* to print it simply replace the declaration with a print statement. For example, instead of *`arrev=( )`* use *`printf %s\ `.* Still, it seems much more practical to call on an actual builtin array as needed and then to *`unset` or `arrev=()`* the variable when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
for i in `printf '%s\n' "${MYARRAY[@]}"|tac`; do echo $i; done
```

The output is:

```
four
three
two
one
```

Limitation: doesn't work if array contain newlines.
As a workaround you may implement function:

```
reverse(){ reversed=();local i;for ((i=$#;i>0;i--)); do reversed+=("${!i}");done; }
```

and use it this way:

```
reverse "${MYARRAY[@]}" && for i in "${reversed[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: That's a complicated way of writing `printf '%s\n' "${MYARRAY[@]}"|tac`.

Comment: It's a way of iterating array in reverse order. You can put anything you want in place of `echo $i`.

Comment: Ah, okay. This breaks in the - admittedly contrived - case of a newline within one array element: `MYARRAY=($'part1\npart2' second)` as `tac` separates by newlines, and not actual array elements.

Comment: Thanks, @Benjamin. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple as a string:

```
% unset c; a="1 2 3 4 5"; for b in $a; do c="$b $c"; done; echo $c
```

5 4 3 2 1

You sure you want array syntax??:

```
 % unset c; declare -a c; a=(1 2 3 4 5); i=0; for b in ${a[*]}; \
    do c[$((${#a[@]}-$i))]=$b; i=$(($i+1)); done; echo ${c[*]}
```

5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 2):

you can also consider using `seq`

```sh
MYARRAY=("one" "two" "three" "four")

for i in $(seq $((${#MYARRAY[@]} - 1)) -1 0); do
    echo ${MYARRAY[$i]}
done
```

in freebsd you can omit -1 increment parameter:

```sh
for i in $(seq $((${#MYARRAY[@]} - 1)) 0); do
    echo ${MYARRAY[$i]}
done
```

Comment: instead of `seq`, you can also get the indices in reverse order using `tac -s' ' <<<${!MYARRAY[@]}` or, if the array has less than 10 entries, using `rev <<<${!MYARRAY[@]}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a sequential numerical array (say to delete bash history) you can just list this in reverse order for instance:

```
for i in {16..10}; do history -d $i; done
```

I realize that this is kind of off topic and I apologize for that however I figured that it was probably worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise limiting one-liner usage for such things and instead write a function that's sourced into your shell or script. Here's an example for newer versions of Bash where it's possible to pass multiple arrays by reference to a function...

```
reverse_array(){
  local -n _source_array_ref="${1}"
  local -n _destination_array_ref="${2}"

  for ((_index=${#_source_array_ref[@]}-1; _index>=0; _index--)); do
    _destination_array_ref+=("${_source_array_ref[$_index]}")
  done
}


_list=(spam ham space)
_new_list=()

reverse_array '_list' '_new_list'

printf '%s\n' "${_new_list[@]}"
#> space
#> ham
#> spam
```

... however, with this technique do be aware that it makes a function that's *impure* (has side-effects), meaning that debugging `_list` or `_new_list` can become difficult when in a Bash scripting mindset... also current examples don't take into account that one could re-run `reverse_array` and end up with `_new_list` appended to multiple times; which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy and intuitive way to reverse an array.

It does it the same way as you would in languages that have car/cdr style list data structures. Build a new list with the elements being pushed in front of each other.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pets=( ant bat cat dog )
pet_rev=()

for pet in ${pets[@]}
do
  # this puts the next pet in front of the ones already in pet_rev 
  pet_rev=( $pet ${pet_rev[@]} )
done

echo "${pet_rev[@]}"
```

The output is of course; `dog cat bat ant`

This could be put in a single line with the reversed array assigned back to the original one. Though doing so would be a little hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here follows another solution but one-liner...

```
$ export MYARRAY=("one" "two" "three" "four")
$ for i in ${!MYARRAY[@]}; do echo ${MYARRAY[-1 - $i]} ; done
four
three
two
one
$
```

That's because you may refer to array items with negatives, so that the very last has -1 index, the second last -2 and so on.

For an array with "holes", by using the array of indexes approach, follows a not so one-liner solution:

```
$ MYARRAY=("one" "two" "three" "four")
$ MYARRAY[45]="forty-five"
$ MYARRAY[83]="eighty-three"
$ MYARRAY+=("a" "b" "c")
$ idxs=( ${!MYARRAY[@]} )
$ for i in ${!idxs[@]} ; do echo ${MYARRAY[${idxs[$((-1 - ${i}))]}]} ; done
c
b
a
eighty-three
forty-five
four
three
two
one
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that does not involve any loop.

Get the full array declaration with `declare -p`, revert the indices and declare a new array. Basically, we want to transform

```
declare -a OLD=([0]="aa" [1]="bb" [2]="cc")
```

into

```
declare -a NEW=([2-0]="aa" [2-1]="bb" [2-2]="cc")
```

That works because the array indices are subject to ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.

Here is a simple implementation that assumes that no array element contains the character '['.

```
A=("aa" "bb" "cc" "dd")

TMP=( "${A[@]}" )           # get a copy of A with contiguous indices
len="${#TMP[@]}"            # get array length.
decl=$(declare -p TMP)      # get full declaration of TMP
decl=${decl#*=}             # remove prefix up to first '=' 
decl="${decl//[/[$len-1-}"  # insert len-1 in front of all indices 
declare -a B=$decl          # and declare our new inverted array  

# B should now contain "dd" "cc" "bb" "aa"
```